# Understanding the pricing of min_idle_instances and min-idle-instances in google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Even after reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=java#min_idle_instances), I'm still not able to understand the utility of using "min-idle-instances" if idle instance is billed the same way as a running instance.

So for example rather than doing "min_instances: 1, min-idle-instances: 1" lets do "min_instances: 2" if it costs the same, and if the purpose is to reduce pending latency, because a "running" instance will be always ready to serve.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding pricing, you're absolutely right.

App Engine charges per instance, whether active or inactive.

`min_idle_instance` is not intended for cost optimization, but rather for reducing latency due to cold starts. It's primarily used for fine-tuning your application to handle unexpected high demand efficiently.

Comment: Great, but still one active instance is better for reducing latency than an idle one right ?

Comment: I believe the effect is similar. `min_idle_instance` is more pertinent in scenarios involving autoscaling. If your application doesn't autoscale due to lack of necessity, then maintaining two instances appears to be roughly equivalent to having one idle instance on standby to manage traffic fluctuations.

Comment: My application does autoscale indeed, I can have more than 10 instances running at some pics of traffic. But still: what will I gain when having idle instances ? it will be more fast to "turn on" sure, but I still prefer an extra running instance if the price is the same, am I clear ?

Comment: Then, setting `min_idle_instance` to 1 could help in smoothing the autoscaling process as the demand increases.

Comment: Ok I finally see it, I think I was focused on the fact that paying for an additional instance that is not used is a "cost effective".